# Translation route in laravel to work sitewide

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My laravel web application runs in two different languages and I'm using a route to set it, like this:

```
Route::get('/br', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return Redirect::to('/')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('locale', "pt-br"));
});
```

This works well, but does not work for all the pages on the website, just for the route itself (myapp.com/br)

I want to send my users links on their language, using a url string to define it, and then redirecting the users to the page itself, which could be any page, for example:

http://www.myapp.com/pt/pricing

This would set language to portuguese, and then redirect them to pricing or any other page on the website that has the /pt in the URL.

Basically I need a wildcard check if "/pt" is in the URL, preferrably through routes.

I know I could do this with a url string, like this:

http://www.myapp.com/pricing?lang=pt

But it seems a bit off my development pattern.

So, I need something like this:

```
Route::get('/br/%anything', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return Redirect::to('/%anything')->withCookie(cookie()->forever('locale', "pt-br"));
});
```

Is there a way to do it with a route in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register your languages first:

```
Route::bind('lang', function($lang){
    $langs = [
        'br' => 'pt-br',
        'pt' => 'pt-pt',
    ];

    return $langs[$lang];
});
```

Then add a pattern for your pages's identifier:

```
Route::pattern('page', '[a-z]+');
```

Now, make a redirection according to `lang/page` url:

```
Route::get('{lang}/{page}', function($lang, $page){
    return redirect()
           ->route($page)
           ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('locale', $lang));
});
```

Results:

- myapp.com/pt/pricing -> myapp.com/pricing (with `pt` at cookie)
- myapp.com/br/pricing -> myapp.com/pricing (with `br` at cookie)
- myapp.com/auth/login -> will not redirect

Comment: what if the user visits some other page like myapp.com/auth/login for example? won't it redirect to /login with 'auth' as cookie?

Comment: No, it does not redirect with cookie, because `{lang}` pattener only is recognized if the first segment of the url only hast exactly two letters.

Comment: Oh, I see.. and one more thing I didn't get.. in Route::pattern('page', '[a-z]+'); why is 'page' also being passed? Didn/t really get the how pattern part works.. Sorry, I'm kinda new to this

Comment: Consider read more about [routes and patterns](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) in official docs, there are some cool facts.